# SQLServer em rede

Tags: sql-server

Tenho o SQLServer 2014 instalado no meu portátil e é nele que programo em visual studio, mas tambem tenho um desktop no qual só está instalado o visual studio porque não tenho muito espaço para ter também o SQLServer. A minha questão é se é possível utilizar o SQL que tenho no portátil usando o desktop.

Comment: sim é possível e fácil. siga estes links: [https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/habilitando-o-acesso-remoto-no-sql-server-2008/) https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/habilitando-o-acesso-remoto-no-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Muito obrigado @Joy Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, basta no seu pc no Visual Studio, adicionar um server na aba (**server explorer**),clica com botão direito e no menu de contexto que abrir vai ter a opção, **add server**, logo em seguida basta entrar com o **ip-do-seu-laptop:porta** onde está rodando seu sql server.